# (Error) Adobe Illustrator with Wine

Tags: wine

I'm relatively new in the world of linux, despite of using it 2 years ago. I tried to install Adobe Illustrator with Wine, and when I tried to launch de app, got me that message:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 64-bit code (0x000000006872cb85).
Register dump:
rip:000000006872cb85 rsp:000000000021d100 rbp:000000000021d230 eflags:00010286 ( R- -- I S - -P- )
rax:0000000000000000 rbx:000000000021d1a8 rcx:ffffffffffffffff rdx:0000000000000000
rsi:00007fffffb9fc20 rdi:0000000000000000 r8:00000000073a1d40 r9:0000000000000028 r10:0000000000000000
r11:00000000073a1d40 r12:0000000000000000 r13:000000000af81268 r14:0000000006849e00 r15:0000000000000000
Stack dump:
0x000000000021d100: 00000000073a1d40 0000000000000028
0x000000000021d110: 00000000073a1d40 000000000b123640
0x000000000021d120: 000000000b123bc0 000000000434fa60
0x000000000021d130: 00000000073a1d40 0000000000000000
0x000000000021d140: 00007fffffb9fc20 0000000000000000
0x000000000021d150: 0000000000000002 0000000000000000
0x000000000021d160: fffffffffffffffe 0000000000000000
0x000000000021d170: 00007fffffb9fc20 fffffffffffffffe
0x000000000021d180: 000000006898b1f0 00000000687c7c79
0x000000000021d190: 00007fffffb9fc20 000000006898b170
0x000000000021d1a0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000021d1b0: fffffffffffffffe 0000000000000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x000000006872cb85 EntryPoint+0xffffffffffffffff() in dvacore (0x000000000021d230)
0x000000006872cb85 EntryPoint+0xffffffffffffffff in dvacore: repne scasw (%rsi)
Modules:
Module Address Debug info Name (114 modules)
PE 220000- 32c000 Deferred shlwapi
PE 330000- 398000 Deferred bib
PE 3a0000- 3f0000 Deferred bibutils
PE 400000- 2268000 Deferred illustrator
PE 2270000- 232a000 Deferred msvcp100
PE 2620000- 2dfc000 Deferred agm
PE 2e00000- 3247000 Deferred cooltype
PE 3250000- 37e0000 Deferred mps
PE 37e0000- 39b5000 Deferred ace
PE 39c0000- 3a34000 Deferred adobexmp
PE 3a40000- 3b5d000 Deferred adobexmpfiles
PE 3b60000- 3bcf000 Deferred are
PE 3bd0000- 3d3b000 Deferred wrservices
PE 3d40000- 3edb000 Deferred adobelinguistic
PE 3ee0000- 4010000 Deferred icuuc40
PE 4010000- 42ed000 Deferred msvcrt
PE 42f0000- 4a60000 Deferred dvaui
PE 4a60000- 4cea000 Deferred comdlg32
PE 4cf0000- 526c000 Deferred comctl32
PE 5270000- 55c1000 Deferred dvaai
PE 55d0000- 5a8f000 Deferred dvaadameve
PE 5a90000- 5b8f000 Deferred boost_regex
PE 5b90000- 5d21000 Deferred exo
PE 5d30000- 5f64000 Deferred adobeowl
00000140 0
0000014c 0
System information:
Wine build: wine-6.0 (Ubuntu 6.0+repack-1ubuntu1)
Platform: x86_64
Host system: Linux
Host version: 5.19.0-38-generic
```

I have insatlled before in linux mint, but i've changed to ubuntu 22.04 and now i can't. Can someone help me?

Comment: If it is working, or not, seems to depend on the versions used, see: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20